# Measuring the peak discharge current of capacitor

Tags: capacitor, current-measurement

I am applying two capacitors conneted in parallel to operate a pulsed plasma thruster. My question is how to calculate the peak discharge current of 2x 8(micro-Farad) capacitors (connected together in parallel) in an RLC circuit?. I am doing this because I want to choose the suitable current probe (a rogowski coil) to measure the current. This rogowski coil has a peak current that must not be exceeded.

Comment: Use the impedance you unload it into as upper limit and then work your way down with smaller ranged coils?

Comment: The braindead way is just to put it in a simulator. That's probably what I would do.

Comment: Show a circuit or do what @pipe says.

Comment: it's a simple series RLC shown here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/RLC_series_circuit_v1.svg/2000px-RLC_series_circuit_v1.svg.png. I thought of substituting (dI/dt)=0 in the second order equation of Kirchhoff's rule (dI/dt)+ (R/L)*I + (Q/LC) = 0 and got the I_peak = (-Q/RC)

Comment: Every discharge circuit got current limiter, check your coil power and design a limiter. Next question maybe "how to set discharge current ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea to simulate it! You can also check R and L and C separately with a source generator and an oscilloscope in order to models R and L and C correctly with the parasitic component. It could have sense if you are not sure for one of them. For example, a single wire has an inductance of about 1nH/mm. Two wires in parallel will have some pF in parasitics. A parasitics R is also here everywhere. And all good inductor have also a parasitics capacitor, that can be deduct with the resonance frequency (that is sometimes given). Etc...